# Angular HttpClientModule request headers

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run an API call using the Angular HttpClientModule:

```
getUser(ticket) {
console.log(ticket); // Returns valid ticket
    return this.http.get('https://myapi/api/v1/flow-analysis', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-Auth-Token', ticket)
    });
  }
```

When I'm running this API call in my client I get the folowing response:

```
'Failed to provide service ticket to validate'
```

I tried to run the same call in POSTMAN, and I got good response:

[image]

I'm using Chrome with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). Not sure if it causes the problem.

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

I'm using Angular 5

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the Content-Type header:

```js
getUser(ticket: string) {
    console.log(ticket); // Returns valid ticket
    let headers: Headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('X-Auth-Token', ticket);

    return this.http.get('https://myapi/api/v1/flow-analysis', {
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight is that better?

Comment: This is not compactiable with the latest Angular. I'm using Angular HttpclientModule. with your solution I get `Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.`

Comment: @TheUnreal these changes worked for me:

`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`
    
`let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();`